# Confused with OpenGL 3+ Core functions and Extensions

Tags: opengl, opengl-3, opengl-4

I am a bit confused as to how some people refer getting pointers to core functions of OpenGL 3.0 and above as "loading OpenGL extensions"...

When I get output of glGetString(GL_EXTENSIONS) it returns me functions which are indeed extensions...

Is there a way to get similar information about core functions? Or should I either trust that they are there if I successfully create a suitable context or check them individually.

Have I understood it right that the extensions actually are some "special" functions and features that a graphics card may support and that feature might or might not someday be approved by ARB?

Comment: https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Load_OpenGL_Functions

Comment: Thank you for your late answer. Managed to study those already and I some what now understand what those are :)